How can I call a custom JavaScript function, to manipulate the HTML5 canvas element, from within the "HTML" section of my Blazor server project?
I have a Blazor server application. On one of my pages I have the standard setup:
MyPage.razor:
@page "/mypage"
<div>
    <!-- stuff here ... -->
</div>

@code {
    // stuff here ...
}

On this page, I am looping through a List like so:
<div>
    @foreach(MyData anData in ListOfMyData){
        // stuff here ...
    }
</div>

Within this loop, I want to create an image with the HTML canvas element based off the data within MyData.
<div>
    @foreach(MyData anData in ListOfMyData){
        <div>
            <canvas id="@anData.id" class="myDataImage"></canvas>
        </div>
    }
</div>

Within the @code section, I am injecting IJSRuntime:
@code {
    [Inject]
    IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
}

And I have my JavaScript code in: MyApp/wwwroot/js/MyJavaScript.js
function drawImage(canvasID, data){
    let thisCanvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
    thisCanvas.width = xxx;
    thisCanvas.height = xxx;
    let ctx = thisCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    // ... more here
}

"Individually", this all works, meaning:

I have successfullly used IJSRuntime before with other custom JavaScript fuctions.
The JavaScript I have works, as I have tested it in a "vanilla" HTML project.

What I am having trouble figuring out is how to call the JavaScript function from within the "HTML" section of my Blazor (.razor) page.

--->>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416580/calling-a-js-function-for-use-in-razor-component-code-file

@Hayden Thank you, I'll give it a shot. At first glance it says "client side", which tells me this is a WebAssembly, whereas I have a server side application. Should it still work?

@Hayden I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I have this in my @code: jsModule = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/JavaScript.js");, and this  in my "HTML" section" @jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("drawImage", anData.myData) but what is getting displayed in the UI is this: System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask

Hi @Brian Try this and tell us the result.

@JasonPan I would love to try this, thank you! However, this page is dynamic, meaning the end user is constantly entering data into a <form></form> on this page, and the ListOfMyData is constantly updating and changing while the page is still loaded.

@JasonPan I did try your code within the method where I get the data, and it works perfectly. How do I go about getting the result into the HTML section of my .razor page?

@Brian Sorry for the late reply, will share my detailed steps for you, have a great day.

Here is my sample code.

MyJavaScript.js
window.drawImage = function (canvasID, data) {
    let thisCanvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
    if (!thisCanvas) return "Canvas not found";
    thisCanvas.width = data.width;
    thisCanvas.height = data.height;
    let ctx = thisCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, data.width, data.height);
    return "Drawing completed";
}

MyData.cs
namespace BlazorCanvasApp.Models
{
    public class MyData
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }
}

MyPage.razor
@page "/mypage"
@using BlazorCanvasApp.Models

<h3>Canvas Sample</h3>

<div>
    @foreach (var anData in ListOfMyData)
    {
        <div>
            <canvas id="@anData.Id" class="myDataImage"></canvas>
            <p>@(drawResults.ContainsKey(anData.Id) ? drawResults[anData.Id] : "Drawing...")</p>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    private List<MyData> ListOfMyData = new List<MyData>();
    private Dictionary<string, string> drawResults = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Mock Data
        ListOfMyData.Add(new MyData { Id = "canvas1", Width = 200, Height = 100 });
        ListOfMyData.Add(new MyData { Id = "canvas2", Width = 150, Height = 150 });

    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            foreach (var anData in ListOfMyData)
            {
                string result = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("drawImage", anData.Id, anData);
                drawResults[anData.Id] = result;
            }
            StateHasChanged(); 
        }
    }
}

Test Result


You should just wrap the js function in a private method and call it from the HTML. I mean, that is if I understood correctly that your issue is calling it from a DOM or a component?


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
